# Grouping by date and combining data from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, group-by, pivot, case-statement

The following are the three tables I have where session.id = signup.session_id AND session.loc_id = location.id. The max override is as the name suggest override the default max capacity for the location hence `IFNULL(session.max_override, location.max_cap)`.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM session;
+----+---------------------+---------------+--------+
| id | date_time           | max_override  | loc_id |
+----+---------------------+---------------+--------+
| 1  | 2014-02-04 10:30:00 |      35       |    2   | 
| 2  | 2014-02-04 17:00:00 |               |    2   | 
| 3  | 2014-02-06 11:30:00 |      50       |    2   | 
| 4  | 2014-02-09 13:30:00 |               |    1   | 
+----+---------------------+---------------+--------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM location;
+-----------------+---------+
| id | location   | max_cap |
+-----------------+---------+
|  1 | up         | 20      |
|  2 | down       | 103     |
|  3 | right      | 50      |
|  4 | left       | 50      |
+-----------------+---------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM signups;
+-----------------+------------+
| id | name       | session_id |
+-----------------+------------+
|  1 | test       |    3       |
|  2 | admin      |    1       |
|  3 | meme       |    2       |
|  4 | anna       |    4       |
+-----------------+------------+
```

The report I am trying to create looks simple but I am not sure how to approach the problem. The following is how I would like the report/output to look like..

```
 mysql> query ouput;
+------------+----------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
| date       | am_time  | am_ses_id | am_spots | pm_time  | pm_ses_id | pm_spots |
+------------+----------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
| 2014-02-04 | 10:30 AM |    1      |    34    | 05:00 PM |     2     |    102   |
| 2014-02-06 | 11:30 AM |    3      |    49    |          |           |          |
| 2014-02-09 |          |           |          | 01:30 PM |     4     |    49    |
+------------+----------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

I can group the date and time correctly and also managed to get the `session_id` to match since it is all within one table but to calculate the am/pm spots which is nothing but counting the records in signups table for a particular session and deducting the value from either the `max_cap` or `max_override` depending on the situation.

THIS is what I tried

Using the following query

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(a.date_time,'%m/%d/%Y') AS ses_date,
    DATE_FORMAT(a.date_time,'%r') AS ses_time,
    a.id,
    COUNT(b.id) as signed_up,
    IFNULL(a.max_override,c.max_cap) AS cap
FROM
    test.session a
    LEFT JOIN
        test.signups b
        ON (b.session_id = a.id)
    LEFT JOIN
        test.location c
        ON (c.id = a.loc_id)
GROUP BY b.session_id
```

I get the following output

```
+------------+----------+--------+-----------+------+
| date       | ses_time | ses_id | signed_up | cap  |
+------------+----------+--------+-----------+------+
| 2014-02-04 | 10:30 AM |    1   |    1      |  35  |
| 2014-02-04 | 05:00 PM |    2   |    1      | 103  |
| 2014-02-06 | 10:30 AM |    3   |    1      |  50  |
| 2014-02-09 | 10:30 AM |    4   |    1      |  50  |
+------------+----------+--------+-----------+------+
```

But I cannot seem to find a way to group it only by the date so the output would appear like desired! I don't know if I should union two queries either.

Comment: what are am_spots and pm_spots?

Comment: the `JOIN` operator lets SQL know how to relate the tables.

Comment: those are just the calculated spots available for either the am (morning) session or pm (afternoon) session. its calculated by counting the records in the signup table and deducting it from max_override if set or max_cap from location table.

Comment: ah I see what you mean now

Comment: what's the cap for 2014-02-04 17:00:00, neither max_override nor max_cap exist

Comment: sorry that was typo on my part! I have corrected the code to show the correct values. Thanks for catching that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very convoluted way of doing it...

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d85ca/11

```
select c.ses_date `date`, a.ses_time am_time, a.id am_ses_id, a.cap-a.signed_up am_spots, 
       b.ses_time pm_time, b.id pm_ses_id, b.cap-b.signed_up pm_spots
from (
    select distinct DATE_FORMAT(a.date_time,'%m/%d/%Y') ses_date
    from session a) c
left join (
    SELECT 
        DATE_FORMAT(a.date_time,'%m/%d/%Y') AS ses_date,
        DATE_FORMAT(a.date_time,'%r') AS ses_time,
        a.id,
        COUNT(b.id) as signed_up,
        IFNULL(a.max_override,c.max_cap) AS cap
    FROM
        session a
        LEFT JOIN
            signups b
            ON (b.session_id = a.id)
        LEFT JOIN
            location c
            ON (c.id = a.loc_id)
    where date_format(a.date_time, '%p') = 'AM'
    GROUP BY b.session_id) a on c.ses_date = a.ses_date
left join (
    SELECT 
        DATE_FORMAT(a.date_time,'%m/%d/%Y') AS ses_date,
        DATE_FORMAT(a.date_time,'%r') AS ses_time,
        a.id,
        COUNT(b.id) as signed_up,
        IFNULL(a.max_override,c.max_cap) AS cap
    FROM
        session a
        LEFT JOIN
            signups b
            ON (b.session_id = a.id)
        LEFT JOIN
            location c
            ON (c.id = a.loc_id)
    where date_format(a.date_time, '%p') = 'PM'
    GROUP BY b.session_id) b on c.ses_date = b.ses_date;
```

Comment: see, all that work, and it's something the UI can solve really simply.

Comment: That is tricky to read! But I will go with it since it appears to the best way. Thanks a LOT for the quick response on that!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the JOIN operator to let the SQL DB know the relationship between the tables.
In this case also, it may be easier to do a subquery to get the count (to avoid `GROUP BY`). I've not separated out AM and PM by day but you could do that.

```
SELECT session.date_time,
    IFNULL(session.max_override,location.max_cap)-(
        SELECT COUNT(signups.id) 
        FROM signups 
        WHERE signups.session_id = session.id) as avail_spots
FROM session LEFT JOIN location ON session.loc_id = location.id;
```

Note the `LEFT JOIN` will include `2014-02-04 17:00:00` with a `NULL` avail_spots since neither max_override nor max_cap have a value, whereas `INNER JOIN` would not report that session at all.

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c847/3)

EDIT: once you have the information by day you can use it on output. Trying to pivot out the times but grouping on the date adds a lot of complexity to the query that could be solved a lot more simply by whatever program you are using for your UI.

Comment: I needed the output to put into a grid but in order for it to work the query result had to be consistent. Thanks for the input also! I will take ur advice and try to develop the code given by user3678068! Thanks again!

Comment: ordering by date you can make the grid using this query without the added complexity. You're making SQL do extra work for little added benefit.